# how to access collection returned by jpql from ejb in managed bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, managed-bean

i have an app where i need to fire a jpql query with sum() and Func(year,...) functions, which means only 2 fields are to be fetched and stored into a collection and then this collection is to be returned to the managed bean. now my question is that how do i use this collection to retrieve each value. below is the session bean and managed bean code:

```
    public Collection getScripQtyYearWise(Integer scripID)
 {
    try
    {
     Collection coll=em.createQuery("select sum(t.tradeExecutedQuantity), FUNC('YEAR',t.tradeDateTime) from TradeStock t where t.scripID.scripID = :scripID group by FUNC('YEAR',t.tradeDateTime) ").setParameter("scripID", scripID).getResultList();
     return coll;
    }catch(Exception e){return null;}
 }
```

eg of data returned: sum(qty)   year
                      210       2011
                      198       2012
i need to extract each of the values in each record returned in followinf managed bean:

```
  objejb=(StockCommodityEJBStateless) new InitialContext().lookup("StockCommodityTest");
 Collection coll=objejb.getScripQtyYearWise(scripID1); // how to use this collection?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coll` is a `Collection` of `Object[]`, so you can parse it like this:

```
    for (Object o : coll) {
        Object[] res = (Object[]) o;
        Object sum = res[0];
        Object year = res[1];

    }
```

If you want a List instead of Object[] you can change your select like this:

```
Collection coll=em.createQuery("select new list(sum(t.tradeExecutedQuantity), FUNC('YEAR',t.tradeDateTime)) from TradeStock t where t.scripID.scripID = :scripID group by FUNC('YEAR',t.tradeDateTime) ").setParameter("scripID", scripID).getResultList();
```

Read more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)!

Answer (score 1):

Such a query will return a `List<Object[]>`. And each Object[] will contain two elements: the sum, and the result of the function call.

So, iterate over the result, and create a meaningful object for each result:

```
public List<ScripQtyYearWise> getScripQtyYearWise(Integer scripID) {
    List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery("...").list();
    List<ScripQtyYearWise> result = new ArrayList<ScripQtyYearWise>(list.size());
    for (Object[] row : list) {
        result.add(new ScripQtyYearWise((Long) row[0], (Date) row[1]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: okay so do i need to create my own entity such as ScripQtyYearWise to create List<ScripQtyYearWise> ?

Comment: It's not an entity, it's a POJO. And yes, to have a List<ScripQtyYearWise>, the ScripQtyYearWise class needs to exist.

Comment: thanks but i used @tibtof's solution and it worked for me, does it have any drawback?

Comment: Yes, it has a drawback. It forces all the clients of your method to know that what is returned is a list of 2 elements, and that the first is a sum that must be cast to a Long, and the second is a year. It's much clearer, self-documentary, robust and safe to return a `List<ScripQtyYearWise>` than a `List<List<Object>>`.